# Where can I find the X-Frame-Option value on Windows Server?

Tags: .net, iis-10, x-frame-options

I have checked the http header section in IIS 10.0 and I have checked the web config file and I can't find the option anywhere but somewhere is setting the X-Frame-Option value to SAMEORIGIN:

> Refused to display 'https://example.co.uk/' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

When I add the X-Frame-Options into the web.config :

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<remove name="X-Powered-By" />
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="allow-from https://example.co.uk/" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I get the following in the console:

> Refused to display 'https://example.co.uk' in a frame because it set
>   multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values
>   ('SAMEORIGIN, allow-from https://example.co.uk/'). Falling back to
>   'deny'.

I really need to add an iframe onto another site so need this current site to allow it to display.  I have full access to both sites/servers.

The site is built in c# .Net and there is no Response headers being set there either - from my searches anyway!

Please could someone explain how this can be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should check the web app documentation to see how to prevent it from generating the X-Frame-Options that way. If you do want to do it alone on IIS, use URL Rewrite module to remove it or modify it, http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2015/12/remove-x-frame-options-sameorigin-http.html

Comment: Post what you learned as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Still working it out. The article was helpful but the site didnt still didnt display. Once I find a solution I will do 

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this I hope this helps. MVC 4 + automatically adds the x-frame-option as sameorigin. So if you set it in IIS or in the config it will fail as it picks up both values. My advice is not to override it and think of another approach, perhaps an API to complete a login page on another site? Most sites will only allow sameorgin these days any way.

However, if you do need to override it you can add the following in your global.asax.cs file under the Application _Start() method:

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

Then you can set the value you want in IIS or directly in the sites web.config.